# Ventana Modal, Obtener Valor Fila,Tabla bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css, mysqli

tengo una duda.

Tengo una tabla en la cual muestro los de un cliente, de una tabla llamada Clients  con campos: user_first, user_last, user_uid...

[image: tabla clientes]

Luego tengo un boton con el simbolo ' # ' que al presionarlo me muestra una ventana modal con valores de otra tabla que tienen relacion con este cliente, la otra tabla se llama ABONOS.

Cada cliente cuenta con ese botoncito ' # ' para mostrar esos datos en la ventana modal.

Como hago para que al presionarlo me detecte el valor de la fila que presiono o el username??

actualmente lo hice rude: `"SELECT loan_id,loan_amount,loan_totalint FROM loans WHERE user_uid='Don mario'";`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero como no se cuantos usuarios o los nombres que tendran como hago para identificar la fila?

Me ayudan porfavor?

mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
       <?php
       $sql2= "SELECT loan_id,loan_amount,loan_totalint FROM loans WHERE 
       user_uid='Don mario'";


       $result2 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql2);

        ?>

        <?php

        echo '

               <!-- Modal -->
               <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
               <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

               <!-- Modal content-->
               <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data- 
               dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               <h4 class="modal-title">Loan Info</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">

               <div class="container table-responsive">

               <table class="table table-hover">
               <thead>
               <tr>  
                 <th width="0.01%">Id</th>   
                 <th width="0.01%">Monto Actual</th>
                 <th width="0.01%">Total Interes</th>    

               </tr>
               </thead>';

               if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0)  
               {  
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))  
               {
               echo' <tbody>

              <tr>
              <td>'.$row["loan_id"].'</td> 

              <td class="loan_amount" data-id2="'.$row["loan_id"].'" 
              >'.$row["loan_amount"].'</td>

              <td class="loan_totalint" data- 
              id3="'.$row["loan_id"].'">'.$row["loan_totalint"].'</td>

              </tr>
              </tbody>';

              }
              echo '

             <tr>  
             <td></td>   
            <td id="loan_amount"></td>
            <td id="loan_totalint"></td>  

            </tr>';

            }

           echo '     

           </table>  
           </div> 


            </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
             dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
            </div>

             </div>
             </div>  ';
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un metodo que muestre los datos del user que quieres, luego para ejecutar la funcion segun el usuario, creas un boton que ejecute ese metodo y dentro le mandas los parametros del usuario, 
En javaScript seria algo mas on menos asi

cuando ejecute la funcion, esta va a saber de que usuario se trata y asi cargara los datos y los mostrara, trata de usar eso con PHP

Comment: La logica lo entiendo amigo, gracias por tu comentario.